# Downloading Scala issues

Tags: scala, installation

**So I need to download scala for one of my classes. I am using a mac pro and the command line to do so. 
I downloaded sbt using homebrew which worked fine. 
After these are the directions given:**

Install the SBT plugin:

mkdir ~/.sbt

mkdir ~/.sbt/0.13

mkdir ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins

echo 'addSbtPlugin("edu.umass.cs" % "cmpsci220" % "3.0.0")' > ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt

**To verify that everything is installed, I have to type 'sbt' to start SBT. Once typed, I should see output that looks like this:**

[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/arjun/.sbt/0.13/plugins

[info] Updating {file:/Users/arjun/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...

[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...

[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/edu.umass.cs/cmpsci/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/3.0.0/jars/cmpsci.jar ...

[info]   [SUCCESSFUL ] edu.cs#cmpsci;3.0.0!cmpsci.jar (1261ms)$

**However, My issue is that once I type 'sbt' to verify things I get this line:**

[info] Set current project to home (in build file:/Users/home/)

**It asks me for a command. I have tried 'run', 'test', 'update'. They all run fine but it keeps asking me a command. 
My goal is to get to the 'sbt console' so I can run scala, import packages, scripts, etc..**

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in the folder of your SBT project to do `sbt run`.

First `cd` into it, then `sbt run` to run it (or `sbt test` or whatever  :))

Answer (score 0):

Type `console` at the sbt prompt.

Edit:

So actually, why do you think this is what you want? Are you trying to run scala code that you're given? Or are you trying to write scala code? If the latter, you should download intellij and the scala plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there is a scala file in the directory you run sbt.

You may also check this for others: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html